# How to override log4j properties for all the imported Java libraries?

Tags: java, clojure, log4j

I am using Clojure but I think this is irrelevant to the question. I would like to override the log4j properties for all the imported libraries and have the exact same format for all. Right now it looks like this:

```
2014-11-26 19:37:19.399 INFO net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authenticated to ae-couchbase10/10.52.61.37:11210
INFO: {:thread-name async-dispatch-2, :first_id batch::test::dev::934ebce6-b78d-4f7c-b297-f636cbfeca0c::8307a507-7deb-40dc-811a-b339148472e7, :time 171.587344, :perf 5.967806110455326}
```

What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XML-based configuration, ie the **`log4j.xml`** file, this will have a higher priority over any `log4j.properties` file that exists in any library.

But if you require the properties file, add an argument to the Java Virtual Machine, e.g.:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.properties KillerApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree witht he use of log4j.xml.

The cloure Luminus framework has a nice default setup for using log4j. Strongly encourage laziness and recommend ahving a look at that for one way of handling log4j setup in clojure projects.